# Sending text from text box inside the div function

Tags: javascript, html

This is an exercise we did in our JavaScript class, 3 days ago. Our prof wanted it to be that if "like"/ "comment" / "share" is clicked it'd be colored and if it was clicked again it'd go back to the original color - like the Facebook type... So anyway, I did get that part. But he also wanted that if something is typed on the textbox and pressed the "Send comment" he wants it to appear on the blank space above or on the div I made... - and I didn't get that part and he never taught us how, he just checked, and recorded what we were able to do... So I want to learn it and actually understand it...

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: So, what specifically is your question?

Comment: Basically I want what is typed on the textbox appear/be sent on my div - How am i going to do that? @Elogent

Comment: If you have the like/comment/share part working you must know the basics of implementing event handlers. So add a click event handler on the "Send comment" and get the input element's value. From the picture it looks like you're close: just add `.value` to the end of your element reference. For more help, please [edit] your question to show the code that you already have.

Comment: How am I suppose to have the text that is typed on the text box appear on my div when I hit the "send comment" button using JavaScript? How am I suppose to code it?

Comment: We have not encountered "event handlers" yet... @nnnnnn

Comment: Then how did you successfully implement the click functionality on like/comment/share? An "event handler" is a function that is called in response to some event such as a "click" or a "keypress". Do you have *any* code that you can show us?

Comment: function myFunction3(){
  var text = document.getElementById('Coms')
    document.getElementById("Div3").innerHTML = text;
   } > the codes i used for that particular function. @nnnnnn

Comment: function myFunction3(){ var text = document.getElementById('Coms').value;document.getElementById("Div3").innerHTML = text; }

Comment: <script>
  function myFunction(){
   var L = document.getElementById("like");
    if(L.style.color == "blue"){
    L.style.color = "black";
    }
    
    else{
     L.style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
  
 </script> - codes in JS i used for the "like"buttons @nnnnnn

Comment: or simply document.getElementById("Div3").innerHTML = document.getElementById('Coms').value;

Comment: thanks @gavgrif ! I finally got it!!!! Thank you, guys!

Comment: no problems - you could even do something funky and put an on-keyup function into it so that as you type into the textbox, the value is passed and displayed in Div3. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The code that you've already tried is pretty close. The problem is that this line:

```
var text = document.getElementById('Coms')
```

...gets you a reference to the 'Coms' textbox itself, it doesn't get its value. That's why in your picture you get the text "[object HTMLInputElement]" displayed.

To get the value of a form element like an input you need the .value property:

```
var text = document.getElementById('Coms').value;
```

In context with your full function:

```
function myFunction3(){
  var text = document.getElementById('Coms').value;
  document.getElementById("Div3").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="text"></div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="textcontent"></input>
    <input type="button" onclick="getdata()" value="Send comment"></input>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata(){
    var textdata = document.getElementById('textcontent').value;
    alert(textdata);
    console.log(2);
    $('#text').text(textdata);
}
</script>
```

This code will help you i think